Plotly graph object Scattermapbox - hover doesn't appear at all
I am trying to create a map with plotly, but hover doesn't appear no matter what I do:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

site_lat = public.Breitengrad
site_lon = public.Längengrad

bezirk = public.Bezirk
adress = public.Standort
ch_table = public.Wickeltisch
price = public.Nutzungsentgelt
time = public.Öffnungszeiten
dis = public.barrierefrei

all = [bezirk, adress, ch_table, price, time, dis]

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
    lat=site_lat,
    lon=site_lon,
    marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
        size=15,
        color='rgb(92, 137, 145)',
        opacity=0.7
    ),
    text=all,
    hoverinfo='text'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
    lat=site_lat,
    lon=site_lon,
    mode='markers',
    marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
        size=10,
        color='rgb(176, 211, 217)',
        opacity=0.4
    ),
    hoverinfo='none'
))

fig.update_layout(
    title='Map of public facilities, Berlin, 2024',
    autosize=True,
    hovermode='closest',
    showlegend=False,
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        bearing=0,
        center=dict(
            lat=52.5197564466725,
            lon=13.406837366714177
        ),
        zoom=10,
        style='light'
    ),
)

fig.update_layout(
    hoverlabel=dict(
        bgcolor="white",
        font_size=16,
        font_family="Rockwell"
    )
)

fig.show()

enter image description here
My last try was to "glue" data I want to appear in a hoover, but it didn't work either.
To be honest, I am currently learning this stuff and was following the examples given.
What have I missed? Is there a better way to make it work?

The code in the reference may be incorrect; try disabling the second hoverinfo='none'. If that does not help, please add the user data used in your map to the question.
